# R ddply vector version

Tags: r, plyr

I am looking for a vector version of ddply.

I would like to do the following:

```
vector_ddply(frame1, frame2, ..., frameN, c("column1", "column2"), processingFunction);
```

Here all frames have both "column1" and "column2" and `processingFunction` takes N parameters.

Note that in my specific case it doesn't make sense to merge the N data frames into one.
The resulting frame would made of the unions of all the keys of the N frames.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Use `merge` with `all=TRUE`? I don't really understand the question. You should provide a simplified example (e.g., some input data, a simplified function and the expected result).

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with some sample data:

```
ll <- list(
  f1  = data.frame( x = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), y = c(1,1,2,2), z = rnorm(4), p = 1:4 ),
  f2  = data.frame( x = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), y = c(1,1,2,2), z = rnorm(4), q = 1:4 ),
  f3  = data.frame( x = c("a", "b", "a", "b"), y = c(1,1,2,2), z = rnorm(4), r = 1:4 )
)
```

### 1. Solution: apply data.frame-wise

You want to `ddply` `processingFunction` on each `data.frame` individually, and combine the results to one resulting `data.frame`:

```
ldply( ll, ddply, .(x, y), summarise, z = processingFunction(z) )
```

### 2. Solution: apply on one rbinded data.frame

You want to apply `processingFunction` over all rows of the `data.frames` at once. So then you should just `rbind` all `data.frames` together to a large one. Just in case this is not directly possible because the individual frames have not all columns in common, you have to `rbind` on the common column subset:

```
commonCols <- Reduce( "intersect", lapply(ll, colnames) )
oneDf <- do.call( "rbind", lapply( ll, "[", commonCols ) )
ddply( oneDf, .(x,y), summarise, z = processingFunction(z) )
```

Comment: Thanks Beasterfield, but this is not what I am looking for. If I understand your solution correctly, you are applying `processingFunction` to each frame independently and then merge the results. Instead, I would like to process the subframes of each frame in `processingFunction` and then group all the results.

Comment: Looks to me like Beasterfield's code is doing what you are asking: process the subframes of each frame in processingFunction and then group all the results.